# Show current date and time in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I have this script to display the current date and time in my web page:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

function startTime() {
var now = new Date();
var h=now.getHours();
var min=now.getMinutes();
var s=now.getSeconds();
var ampm=(now.getHours()>11)?"PM":"AM";
var d=now.getDay();
var y=now.getFullYear();
var mon=now.getMonth();
var da=now.getDate();
var endings=["st","nd","rd","th"];
var dayendings=[0,1,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,0,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,1];
var days=["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
var months=["January","February","March","April", "May", "June","July","August","September", "October", "Novemeber","Decemeber"];
if (h>12) {h-=12}
if (h==0) {h=12};
if (min<10) {min="0"+min}
if (s<10) {s="0"+s}
da+=endings[dayendings[da]];
if (da<10) {da="0"+da};
d=days[d];
mon=months[mon-1];
document.getElementById("time").innerHTML=d+", "+mon+" "+da+", "+y+" "+h+":"+min+":"+s+" "+ampm;
var tim = setTimeout("startTime()",1000);
}

</script>
```

But the result is like this:

```
Friday, April NaN, 2012 6:37:36 PM
```

How can I make `April NaN, 2012` right? It must be the date today which is `May 25,2012`

Answer (score 4):

At the very least you should change

```
da+=endings[dayendings[da]];
```

to

```
da+=endings[dayendings[da - 1]];
```

because right now it has an off-by-one bug (`da` is 1 to 31, but the indexes on `dayendings` are 0 to 30).

This should immediately fix your problem if "today" is the 31st of the month.

Fixes are also needed for the values in `dayendings`, as `4` is not meaningful there.

On a side note, you really should ditch this code for [something better](http://momentjs.com/). Wouldn't you prefer it like this?

```
function startTime() {
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML =
        moment().format("dddd, MMMM Do, YYYY h:mm:ss A");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `var dayendings=[0,1,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,0,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,1];` includes some `4` values. Yet, `var endings=["st","nd","rd","th"];` has only a length of 4, so that it will return undefined when you access `endings[4]`.

Also, you may get an off-by-one-error because `da` is in the range `1` to `31`, which are not the indizes of your `dayendings` array.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your logic for the counter is not correct.
Try the following code:

```
function makeArray() {
for (i = 0; i<makeArray.arguments.length; i++)
this[i + 1] = makeArray.arguments[i];
}
var now = new Date();
var h=now.getHours();
var min=now.getMinutes();
var s=now.getSeconds();
var ampm=(now.getHours()>11)?"PM":"AM";
var months = new makeArray('January','February','March','April','May',
'June','July','August','September','October','November','December');
var date = new Date(); 
var day = date.getDate();
var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
var yy = date.getYear();
var year = (yy < 1000) ? yy + 1900 : yy;
var endings=["st","nd","rd","th"];
var dayendings=[0,1,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,0,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,1];
var days=["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"];

document.write(days[date.getDay()] + " " + months[month]+ " " + day + ", " + year + " " + h + ":" + min + ":" + s + " " + ampm);
```

Comment: this works, but i need the time to be refreshed at every second

Comment: In that case just have the function call itself.Put the var tim=settimout(...) right after document.write... This link can give you an example. Hope this helps. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Comment: As a side note the below answers are cleaner, so once you get it working where it is updating as you need it you might want to re-factor the script.

Answer (score 0):

I've a relatively simple DateTime object in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vwvtq/). May be useful? In your case, using this object, this command would show the date in the format you want (apart from the PM/AM time formatting)

```
XDate({date:new Date,lang:'EN'}).format('WD, MM dd, yyyy, hh:mm:se0');
//=> Friday, May 25 2012, 13:05:03
```

Answer (score 0):

first generate this function and save as .js file

```
function date_time(id) {
    date = new Date;
    year = date.getFullYear();
    month = date.getMonth();
    months = new Array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'Jully', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');
    d = date.getDate();
    day = date.getDay();
    days = new Array('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday');
    h = date.getHours();
    if (h < 10) {
        h = "0" + h;
    }
    m = date.getMinutes();
    if (m < 10) {
        m = "0" + m;
    }
    s = date.getSeconds();
    if (s < 10) {
        s = "0" + s;
    }
    result = '' + days[day] + ' ' + months[month] + ' ' + d + ' ' + year + ' ' + h + ':' + m + ':' + s;
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = result;
    setTimeout('date_time("' + id + '");', '1000');
    return true;
}
```

then use this code on your html page to display the current time and date

```
<script type="text/javascript"> window.onload = date_time('date_time'); </script>
```

dont forget the script tag on the head part of your page:
ex